# How can I sort a multidimensional array using php?

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

Hi I have to sort this array in desc. order on the basis of ratingVal using php. How can I do that.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 26
            [raCnt] => 6
            [sRate] => 18
            [ratingVal] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 714
            [raCnt] => 3
            [sRate] => 14
            [ratingVal] => 4.6666666666667
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 14
            [raCnt] => 4
            [sRate] => 12
            [ratingVal] => 3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 290
            [raCnt] => 2
            [sRate] => 10
            [ratingVal] => 5
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 194
            [raCnt] => 2
            [sRate] => 8
            [ratingVal] => 4
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 134
            [raCnt] => 2
            [sRate] => 6
            [ratingVal] => 3
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [rating_postid] => 707
            [raCnt] => 1
            [sRate] => 5
            [ratingVal] => 5
        )

)
```

Comment: I retagged your question to use more appropriate tags, e. g. dont use the PHP 5.3 tag if you actually do use 5.2.X.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`usort`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php):

```
function sortIt( $a, $b ){
    return $b['ratingVal'] - $a['ratingVal'];
}

usort( $yourArray, "sortIt" );
```

For ascending order, swap the `$a` and `$b` in the subtraction.

The `usort` function allows you to create your own custom sort function

Comment: +1 (a) because your code is the way to do this and (b) because I stole it for my answer!

Comment: Any reason you didn't use `function sortIt($a, $b) {return $b['ratingVal']-$a['ratingVal'];} `?

Answer (score 1):

If you retrieve this data from mysql database (as I see, mysql tag is specified), you may use ORDER BY statement in your query.

If this is not suitable, you'll have to implement comparison function and use [usort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function.

Answer (score 1):

You've tagged your code "php5.3", so I'm going to give a 5.3-specific answer.

*Adapting Harmen's code:*

```
usort( $yourArray, function($a, $b) {
    if( $a['ratingVal'] == $b['ratingVal'] )
        return 0;
    return ( $a['ratingVal'] < $b['ratingVal'] ) ? 1 : -1;
} );
```

This uses [`usort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and [anonymous functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php), a new addition in PHP 5.3.

Comment: sorry sir I am using php 5.2.6